# Find out the page count of a multipage tiff using the CImg Library

Tags: c++, cimg

Has one of you ever tried to find out the page count of a multi-page TIFF file usign the [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/) library?

I'm trying to calculte the histograms for every single page in the file.

This is my code to load the TIFF file and create an Image object:

```
#define cimg_use_tiff
#include <CImg.h>
using namespace cimg_library;

void reader::read_tiff(char * filename){
  CImg<short> img(filename);
}
```

I could propably try to use the

```
CImg<T>::load_tiff (const char *const filename, const unsigned int first_frame=0, const unsigned   int last_frame=~0U, const unsigned int step_frame=1)`
```

function and check if the returned image is null / an exception is thrown. This does not seem like a clean way to to what I want. Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Well the solution seems to be simple. I just have to use the dimensions of the picture to calculate a pixel offset for each page.

The image.size() equals to width*height*page_number.

Comment: Another solution:

One can just read the TIFF into an CImgList<T> and iterate over it. The list contains images for every single page of the TIFF file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the CImgList::load_tiff() function will be your friend.
A multi-page tiff file may contain several images with different sizes, so
it is better to use a CImgList to get the result, as any image of the list can
have a different size (which is not the case for each z-slice of a CImg).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already answered the question in my own comment, but it feels comfortable to know, that someone else would do it the same way.